# Spark Streaming With Kafka Direct approach: horizontal scalability issue

Tags: spark-streaming

I am facing a problem in using spark streaming with Apache Kafka where Spark is deployed on yarn. I am using Direct Approach (No Receivers) to read data from Kafka with 1 topic and 48 partitions. With this setup on a 5 node (4 worker) spark cluster (24 GB memory available on each machine) and spark configurations (spark.executor.memory=2gb, spark.executor.cores=1), there should be 48 executors on Spark cluster (12 executor on each machine).

Spark Streaming documentation also confirms that there is a one-to-one mapping between Kafka and RDD partitions. So for 48 kafka partitions, there should be 48 RDD partitions and each partition is being executed by 1 executor.But while running this, only 12 executors are created and spark cluster capacity remains unused & we are not able to get the desired throughput.

It seems that this Direct Approach to read data from Kafka in Spark Streaming is not behaving according to Spark Streaming documentation. Can anyone suggest, what wrong I am doing here as I am not able to scale horizontally to increase the throughput.

Comment: *But while running this, only 12 executors are created and spark cluster capacity remains unused.* That has nothing to do with Kafka. How are you calling your spark-submit? Also, why are you creating so many executors with so little resources? Maybe you want to utilize dynamic allocation instead.

Comment: Added to your conf parameters, there are two more. SPARK_WORKER_CORES and SPARK_WORKER_MEMORY. examp.
export SPARK_WORKER_CORES=6 #to set the number of cores to use on this machine
export SPARK_WORKER_MEMORY=12G #to set how much total memory workers have to give executors (e.g. 1000m, 2g)

And one more variable i am using in my code
    // spark.cores.max : the maximum amount of CPU cores to request for the application from across the cluster (not from each machine).
    sparkConf.set("spark.cores.max", "16")

You can change and analyse the results with these.